# Append to ul element within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm appending to below div with id "toadd" using this javascript :

```
 $("#toadd").append("<li><a href=\"acura.html\"></a></li>");

<div id="toadd" data-role="content">
        <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
</ul>
```

Is it possible to append to 'ul' element within the div? something like

```
 $("#toadd.ul").append("<li><a href=\"acura.html\"></a></li>");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it without . between #toadd and ul:

```
$("#toadd ul").append("<li><a href=\"acura.html\"></a></li>");
```

Edit: `$("#toadd.ul")` means you are looking the element that has id="toadd" and has a class named "ul". 
`$("#toadd ul")` selects all ul that are enclosed within #toadd element.